# Unable to query using 4 conditions with WHERE clause

Tags: where-clause

I am trying to query a database to obtain rows that matches 4 conditions.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
$result = db_query("SELECT * FROM transportesgeneral WHERE CiudadOrigen LIKE '$origen%' AND DepartamentoOrigen LIKE '$origendep' AND DepartamentoDestino LIKE '$destinodep' AND CiudadDestino LIKE '$destino%'");
```

But it is not working; Nevertheless, when I try it using only 3 conditions; ie:

```
$result = db_query("SELECT * FROM transportesgeneral WHERE CiudadOrigen LIKE '$origen%' AND DepartamentoOrigen LIKE '$origendep' AND DepartamentoDestino LIKE '$destinodep'");
```

It does work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Or is it not possible at all?

Comment: What result do you get from the 2nd (working) query? And what data do you have in database? Without knowing your data one can not tell you why your query is not showing the desired result. And what does "it is not working" mean? What is the expected result compared to the result you get?

Comment: It is surely possible.  It's just there is no record that CiudadDestino field starting with $destino with the other criterias at the same time since you are using AND in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your clarification **smozgur**.
Apparently this was the problem:
I was trying to query the database by using the word that contained a tittle "Petén" so I changed the database info and replaced that word to the same one without the tittle "Peten" and it worked.
Now, im not sure why it does not accept the tittle but that was the problem.
If you have any ideas on how I can use the tittle, I would appreciate that very much.